# Difference Integration results from mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

[image]

N[Integrate[.]] gives me a quite large number while NIntegrate[.] gives me a small one. According to plot of integrand, it seems the numerical integration is more reasonable. It would be extremely helpful if someone can explain as to what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not evaluating your `N[ Integrate[...]]` with enough precision.  E.g.

```
Integrate[(1 - t^2)^8/(100 - t), {t, -1, 1}] // 
 N[#, 40] &
```

Yields:

> 0.005990798933337302015050961985659986308362

Matching your `NIntegrate`.

Why does it get confused // need any extra precision?  You're cancelling very large numbers:

```
Integrate[(1 - t^2)^8/(100 - t), {t, -1, 1}]
```

yields

```
-(18004190799729005916153364606626760/9009) - 
 99920027994400699944002799920001 Log[99] + 
 99920027994400699944002799920001 Log[101]
```

Notice how many digits must cancel to get to $\sim.00599$.

Comment: Many thanks. It is indeed a precision problem!

Comment: Sure! In the future, you'll want to include your Input code inline (using \` or indention), so people can just import your code from your question.   In this case was easy enough to read off the image.  In fact you may want to edit your question to just include `N[Integrate[(1 - t^2)^8/(100 - t), {t, -1, 1}]]` vs `NIntegrate[(1 - t^2)^8/(100 - t), {t, -1, 1}]`